# Trouble with Unity Camera Script Expected ";" at line of code

Tags: unity-game-engine

Having Trouble with a expected ";" in the line of

"Vector2 view - new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);"

Was wondering does anyone know why I am getting this issue?

```
public class Cam_FPS : MonoBehaviour{
Vector2 Camview;
public float sensitivity;
GameObject mainplayer;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    mainplayer = this.transform.parent.gameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");

    Vector2 view - new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);
    Camview +- view * sensitivity;

    Camview.y = Mathf.Clamp (Camview.y, -80f, 80);

    transform.localRotation - Quaternion.AngleAxis(-Camview.y, Vector3.right);
    mainplayer.transform.localRotation - Quaternion.AngleAxis(Camview.x, mainplayer.transform.up);


}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're suffering from code blindness

`Vector2 view - new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);`

You meant

`Vector2 view = new Vector2 (horizontal, vertical);`

Note the equals.. you cant declare a variable and subtract nothing from an unmade container :)

same for `Camview +- view * sensitivity;` and `transform.localRotation - Quaternion.AngleAxis(-Camview.y, Vector3.right);` and `mainplayer.transform.localRotation - Quaternion.AngleAxis(Camview.x, mainplayer.transform.up);`  you didnt mean "-" you meant "=" (most likely)

Comment: Also the line directly below that, `Camview +- view * sensitivity;` will not compile. I suspect `+=`

And furtherdown also 2 more lines about `localRotation`